# Slideshow Pro Director Mobile XML

Tags: php, javascript, xml, gallery, slideshow

Apparently in Slideshow Pro Director Mobile Version, the XML cannot be taken from a different source other than that output by the Director itself.

Which scripts need I modify and how in order to pass my custom XML?